# Return null from eloquent relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have this relationship in one of my model classes:

```
public function userLike()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return $this->hasOne('App\Like')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

    // RETURN NULL IF RECORD DOESN'T EXIST?
}
```

As you can see, it checks if the user is logged in and returns the `Like` record. However, how can I return null if the record doesn't exist?

I tried this:

```
public function userLike()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return $this->hasOne('App\Like')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

    return null;
}
```

But I get the error:

> local.ERROR: exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
>   'Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null' in
>   /var/www/social/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:680

As a side question, am I doing this right? Is this the correct way of doing this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it is the right way to do this. In your model you should only declare your relationships:

```
public function userLike()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Like');
}
```

And then in a controller or something you go get the like of your user like this:

```
class LikesController extends Controller {

    public function getLike()
    {
        $like = null;
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $like = Like::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        }
    }
}
```

So we have a `getLike()` function that get the like of a user from your model `Like` where the user_id is equal to the authenticated user's id.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is the correct answer, logic should never be used in a relationship method. It's there only to define the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure! But I think it is possible to use count! When it returns 0 you know that there are no records, so you can return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this style in your Like Model :

```
    // return the number of likes 
function userLikes()
{
    $count = $this->where('user_id', $this->post_id)->count();
    // check if not null 
    return $count ? $count : 0; // if null return 0
}
```